# Rendering parameters incorrect when multiple of same rendering

Tags: sitecore, glass-mapper, sitecore-mvc, sitecore8

I'm having an issue with a rendering I'm building in Sitecore 8 Update 3, using MVC with Glass Mapper v4.

I have a `Feature Promo` rendering that has a Rendering Parameter Template `Feature Promo Parameters` which defines a droplist field named `Align` with the possible values `Left` and `Right`.

When in Experience Editor and Preview mode the rendering renders correctly and when debugging `RenderingContext.Current["Parameters"]` contains `Align=Left` or `Align=Right` accordingly, and Glass maps this correctly to my POCO.

However, when in web mode, the first rendering has `Align=Left` as its parameter, all subsequent renderings of the same type have `Align` with no value.

Checking the layout XML in the web database via Sitecore Rocks, I can see the parameters are there correctly:

```
<r p:p="1" xmlns:p="p" xmlns:s="s">
    <d id="{FE5D7FDF-89C0-4D99-9AA3-B5FBD009C9F3}">
        <r p:before="r[@uid='{CAE5DB0F-1971-4931-939B-9F7DB14AF0F8}']" 
           s:ds="{F63266A5-CC62-4915-9D89-CB01C7A0D05A}" 
           s:id="{6BA52384-D976-499D-8A0D-7F729EB4376B}" 
           s:par="Align=Left" s:ph="main" 
           uid="{4CBD0824-D232-46F9-8763-295D3B493A4F}"/>
        <r p:before="r[@uid='{12A7C72A-1821-4F8D-9A87-745604BE5106}']" 
           s:ds="{C50C7579-3680-46C3-93B2-9429EB9E0100}" 
           s:id="{6BA52384-D976-499D-8A0D-7F729EB4376B}" 
           s:par="Align=Right" s:ph="main" 
           uid="{CAE5DB0F-1971-4931-939B-9F7DB14AF0F8}"/>
        <r p:before="*[1=2]" uid="{12A7C72A-1821-4F8D-9A87-745604BE5106}"/>
    </d>
</r>
```

No matter what I do, the second (and any subsequent renderings of the same type) doesn't get the specified parameter value.

The code of the rendering is as follows:

```
@model Promo
@{
    var settings = Html.Glass().GetRenderingParameters<FeaturePromoParameters>();
    var alignment = "feature-promo-style-a";
    if (settings != null && settings.Align.EqualsText("Right")) {
        alignment = "feature-promo-style-b";
    }
}

<div class="feature-promo @alignment">
    <div class="layout layout-a">
         <div class="region region-a">
            <div class="region-inner">
                <div class="feature-promo-image-container">
                    @Html.Glass().Editable(m => m.Image)
                </div>
                <div class="block block-size-b feature-promo-text">
                    @if (Html.Glass().IsInEditingMode || !Model.PreTitle.IsEmptyOrNull()) {
                        <div class="pre-title">@Html.Glass().Editable(m => m.PreTitle)</div>
                    }
                    @if (Html.Glass().IsInEditingMode || !Model.Title.IsEmptyOrNull()) {
                        <h2 class="h3 color-a">@Html.Glass().Editable(m => m.Title)</h2>
                    }
                    @Html.Glass().Editable(m => m.Body)
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Can anyone advise what I'm doing wrong, or if I've found a random bug?

**Update for Marek Musielak:**

OK, its now only hitting the breakpoint once -- and has the uid of the first rendering on the page: `{4CBD0824-D232-46F9-8763-295D3B493A4F}`. Could this turn out to be something dynamic placeholders related?

`RenderingContext.CurrentOrNull.Rendering["Parameters"] = "Align=Left"`

Comment: Can you check what is `RenderingContext.CurrentOrNull.Rendering.UniqueId` value before executing `var settings = ...` code? Does it match concurrent rendering unique ids? And what is `RenderingContext.CurrentOrNull.Rendering["Parameters"]` value?

Comment: Are other renderings displayed? Or just the first one? Can you login to sitecore desktop, switch to web database and check presentation details of you item? Do you have a code which hides renderings when datasource is missing? Are datasources/templates/other required items all published? When you say it works in Preview Mode and doesn't in Web Mode, I'm 90% sure it's all related to publishing. You can try to republish the whole site.

Comment: Can you post the model for FeaturePromoParameters?

Comment: Hi @MichaelEdwards, it is a simple POCO with a string property named "Align". Glass wasn't at fault here, my own stupidity and/or Sitecore caching being funny (see my answer below).

Comment: Thanks for the info, that is annoying

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This appears to be due to caching... oh the shame.

The renderings had `Cacheable` unchecked, and no other caching settings selected.

I've just updated them to have `Cacheable` checked and `Vary by Parameters` checked, re-published and its now working correctly.

I would have thought that having `Cacheable` off would mean the rendering would not be cached, but apparently not.

Thanks.